# tkinter root.destroy() without killing the whole window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am recreating the game [Wordle](https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html) for practice.

I am trying to find a function that allows me to destroy all widgets in my tkinter window.

`root.destroy()` isn't a solution because it just closes the whole window.

I want to use this function to, whenever we win the game, restart the whole program without having to manually do it.

Program:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from english_words import english_words_alpha_set
import time

guess = "bored"
guess = guess.upper()
word=""
a=0
def callback1(var, index, mode):
    root.entry2.configure(state="normal")
    root.entry2.focus()
    root.entry1.configure(state="disabled")
    root.hasfocus = "entry2"

def callback2(var, index, mode):
    root.entry3.configure(state="normal")
    root.entry3.focus()
    root.entry2.configure(state="disabled")
    root.hasfocus = "entry3"

def callback3(var, index, mode):
    root.entry4.configure(state="normal")
    root.entry4.focus()
    root.entry3.configure(state="disabled")
    root.hasfocus = "entry4"

def callback4(var, index, mode):
    root.entry5.configure(state="normal")
    root.entry5.focus()
    root.entry4.configure(state="disabled")
    root.hasfocus = "entry5"

def callback5(var, index, mode):
    root.entry5.configure(state="disabled")
    root.hasfocus = "none"

def newRow():
    boxes = [root.box1, root.box2, root.box3, root.box4, root.box5]
    
    word = root.name1.get() + root.name2.get() + root.name3.get() + root.name4.get() + root.name5.get()
    word=word.upper()

    root.greenBoxes=0

    def checkBg():
        if word[a] == guess[a]:
            root.greenBoxes=root.greenBoxes+1
            print("greenBoxes=", root.greenBoxes)
            return '#538D4E'
        elif word[a] in guess:
            return '#B59F3B'
        else:
            return '#3A3A3C'
        
    root.entry1.destroy()
    root.entry2.destroy()
    root.entry3.destroy()
    root.entry4.destroy()
    root.entry5.destroy()
    
    a=0
    while a < 5:
        boxes[a].configure(text=word[a], bg=checkBg(), fg = "white")
        a=a+1
    
    if root.greenBoxes == 5: #if player won:
        root.WinMsg = Label(root, height=2, width=28, bg='#2d2d2f', fg='white', text='You\'ve won! The word was \"' + guess[0] + guess[1:5].lower() +"\"", font="Calibri 20")
        root.WinMsg.place(x=65, y=100) #say that he won
        #*destroy all widgets*
        root.CreateWindow() #remake all widgets (to start a new game)
        return

    root.rows = root.rows+1
    if root.rows < 6: #if player still have any try
        root.d=root.d+70
        root.createBoxes()
        root.createEntry()
    else: #if player lost
        root.GameOverMsg = Label(root, height=2, width=28, bg='#2d2d2f', fg='white', text='You\'ve lost! The word was \"' + guess[0] + guess[1:5].lower() +"\"", font="Calibri 20")
        root.GameOverMsg.place(x=65, y=100) #says that he lost
        #*destroy all widgets*
        root.CreateWindow() #remake all widgets (to start a new game)
        return


    

class root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(root, self).__init__()
        
        self.title("Wordle")
        self.minsize(580,465)
        self.windowBG = '#121213'

        self.CreateWindow()

    def CreateWindow(self):
        self.configure(bg=self.windowBG)

        self.hasfocus = ""
        self.d=0
        self.rows=0
        self.greenBoxes = 0

        self.createBoxes()
        self.createEntry()
        self.backspace = Button(self, text="Backspace", width=8, font ="Calibri 18", command=self.do_backspace)
        self.backspace.place(x=465, y=62)

        self.enter = Button(self, text="Enter", width=6, font ="Calibri 18", command=self.do_enter)
        self.enter.place(x=480, y=125)


    def createBoxes(self):
        self.box1 = tk.Label(self, text="", font="Calibri", height=2, width=6, bg="#3A3A3C")
        self.box1.place(x=70, y=30+self.d)
        self.box2 = tk.Label(self, text="", font="Calibri", height=2, width=6, bg="#3A3A3C")
        self.box2.place(x=150, y=30+self.d)
        self.box3 = tk.Label(self, text="", font="Calibri", height=2, width=6, bg="#3A3A3C")
        self.box3.place(x=230, y=30+self.d)
        self.box4 = tk.Label(self, text="", font="Calibri", height=2, width=6, bg="#3A3A3C")
        self.box4.place(x=310, y=30+self.d)
        self.box5 = tk.Label(self, text="", font="Calibri", height=2, width=6, bg="#3A3A3C")
        self.box5.place(x=390, y=30+self.d)


    def do_backspace(self):
        if self.hasfocus == "entry1":
            pass
        elif self.hasfocus == "entry2":
            self.entry1.configure(state="normal")
            self.entry1.delete(0, 'end')
            self.entry1.configure(state="normal")
            self.entry1.focus()
            self.hasfocus="entry1"
            self.entry2.configure(state="disabled")
        elif self.hasfocus == "entry3":
            self.entry2.configure(state="normal")
            self.entry2.delete(0, 'end')
            self.entry2.configure(state="normal")
            self.entry2.focus()
            self.hasfocus="entry2"
            self.entry3.configure(state="disabled")
        elif self.hasfocus == "entry4":
            self.entry3.configure(state="normal")
            self.entry3.delete(0, 'end')
            self.entry3.configure(state="normal")
            self.entry3.focus()
            self.hasfocus="entry3"
            self.entry4.configure(state="disabled")
        elif self.hasfocus == "entry5":
            self.entry4.configure(state="normal")
            self.entry4.delete(0, 'end')
            self.entry4.configure(state="normal")
            self.entry4.focus()
            self.hasfocus="entry4"
            self.entry5.configure(state="disabled")
        else:
            self.entry5.configure(state="normal")
            self.entry5.delete(0, 'end')
            self.entry5.configure(state="normal")
            self.entry5.focus()
            self.hasfocus="entry5"

    def do_enter(self):
        if len(self.name1.get() + self.name2.get() + self.name3.get() + self.name4.get() + self.name5.get()) == 5:
            newRow()
        else:
            self.FiveLetterWord = Label(self, height=2, width=22, bg='#2d2d2f', fg='white', text='Word must be of 5 letters', font="Calibri 20", background=self.windowBG,highlightbackground='#3A3A3C', highlightthickness=2)
            self.FiveLetterWord.place(x=100, y=100)
            self.update_idletasks()
            self.after(3000)
            self.FiveLetterWord.destroy()

    def createEntry(self):
        
        self.name1 = StringVar()
        self.entry1 = ttk.Entry(self, width=2, textvariable = self.name1, font="Calibri 15", justify='center')
        self.entry1.place(x=90, y=40+self.d)

        self.name2 = StringVar()
        self.entry2 = ttk.Entry(self, width=2, textvariable = self.name2, font="Calibri 15", justify='center')
        self.entry2.place(x=170, y=40+self.d)
        self.entry2.configure(state="disabled")

        self.name3 = StringVar()
        self.entry3 = ttk.Entry(self, width=2, textvariable = self.name3, font="Calibri 15", justify='center')
        self.entry3.place(x=250, y=40+self.d)
        self.entry3.configure(state="disabled")

        self.name4 = StringVar()
        self.entry4 = ttk.Entry(self, width=2, textvariable = self.name4, font="Calibri 15", justify='center')
        self.entry4.place(x=330, y=40+self.d)
        self.entry4.configure(state="disabled")

        self.name5 = StringVar()
        self.entry5 = ttk.Entry(self, width=2, textvariable = self.name5, font="Calibri 15", justify='center')
        self.entry5.place(x=410, y=40+self.d)
        self.entry5.configure(state="disabled")

        self.entry1.focus() ; hasfocus = "entry1"
        self.name1.trace_add("write", callback1)
        self.name2.trace_add("write", callback2)
        self.name3.trace_add("write", callback3)
        self.name4.trace_add("write", callback4)
        self.name5.trace_add("write", callback5)


        
root=root()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `winfo_children` to get a list of all child widgets of the root window, and then you can iterate over the list to destroy each child.

```
for child in root.winfo_children():
    child.destroy()
```

From that point on, you have a root window with nothing in it.